# How does one get number of full days and half days from a start and end date

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, datetime, time

### Background

I've been working on some reporting views that get a multi-day work shift and are supposed to do some calculations based on data, but I'm a bit stuck here.
A typical shift is either 3 calendar days usually 1 half-day and two full days, or a whole week consisting of 2 half-days (end and start) and 5 full days.

### Specifications

I have the following specifications for what is a full day and half-day. These rules are based on regulation and can't be changed.

- 2 half-days != 1 full-day, the 2 halves is more "valuable"
- Given a `started_at` iso datetime and `end_at` iso datetime
- I want to get two numbers, full_days, and half_days
- A half day is

  - A day at the **start** of the range starting **at or after 12.00**
  - A day at the **end** of the range which ends **before 19.00**
- A full day is

  - A day within the range (traditional 24hours)
  - A day at the **start** of the range starting **before 12.00**
  - A day at the **end** of the range which ends **at or after 19.00**

I'm thinking either a row per full-day and half-day or an aggregated row with half_days and full_days as two separate columns would be ideal in the view to connect it with my other views.

### Simplified model

I simplified the data model to leave out unnecessary columns.

```sql
create table if not exists [trip]
(
    trip_id    integer
        constraint trip_pk
            primary key,
    started_at text default (datetime('now')),
    end_at     text default (datetime('now'))
);
```

And I'm a bit stuck with how I should design this query. A simple time delta doesn't work.

SQLFiddle with sample data and answers: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/de7551/2

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate your half day and full day criteria a little more?

i couldn't get this part of the question....

what i get at this moment is: 

for half day=>>> start >='12' and end >='19:00'
for full day=>>> start <'12' and end <'19:00'

you mean somebody is on half day if he CheckIN after 12 and checkout after 19
and its a full day if he just checkIN before 12 and can checkout anytime before 19:00 is it so?

Comment: I tried to be pretty specific, please tell me what's unclear. A starting day in the range is a full day if it starts before 12:00, otherwise it's a half day. A ending day in the range is a full day if it ends after 19:00, otherwise it's a half day.
Edit: Found a mistake in my specs for ending days, fixed it.

Comment: ok, its fine after the update let me share the answer, i will be sharing it in term of sql sudo  code

Comment: I updated the fiddle with some more examples 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/de7551/2

Comment: I think I solved it, I manually checked the answer for a sample of real data and all answers came out correct, commented it below. Not the prettiest query but gets the job done. I'm surprised how simple the answer turned out to be in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this with a CTE which calculates the day span (number of days the shift spans). Since half days are always 1, 2 or 0 (only occur on end and start) we don't actually need to consider each day by itself.

You can use julianday to get the day as a number, however julian days start at noon so you'll need to subtract 0.5 to get the "actual" day for your calculation. Floor the ending day to avoid a to long span if the end time is later then the start time on each respective day, and round up the result to include partial days as a spanned day.

At this point we can calculate number of half days by checking the end and start. To get the number of full days we simply subtract the half days from the result.

```sql
with trip_spans as (
select
    ceil(julianday(end_at)-0.5 - floor(julianday(started_at)-0.5)) day_span
    , t.*
    , (
        iif(time(started_at) > time('12:00'), 1, 0)
        +
        iif(time(end_at) <= time('19:00'), 1, 0)
     ) half_days
    from trip t
)
select
    trip_spans.*
    , day_span-half_days full_days
from trip_spans
```